# Software Project Management systems

Tags: mercurial, projects, tracker

Ok, so I've only recently started getting serious about learning how to program, and I've started using Mercurial to manage my projects. I chose Mercurial over SVN because of it's ability to commit changes to a repo while not connected to the internet (these days I find myself in areas without internet access). I'm looking for a piece of software (preferably free, because I'm on a really tight budget :-P) that will allow me to manage a bug database and TODO list for each of my projects without requiring an internet connection. Is there anything out there that'll allow me to do exactly that (maybe more)? I'd prefer something that can work alongside Mercurial, because it'd be a pain to switch source control systems at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it's been a few days and I still haven't found anything that's suitable for my needs. Fossil sounds great, but I miss the Windows shell extensions that TortoiseHg provides (I don't like working on command lines), dotProject is a hosted solution and if I want to run it locally I have to set up WAMP. The BugsEverywhere repo seems to be down (I cant get anything from it using bzr), and Artemis is good but its easier for me to work with something that has a GUI. I found FogBugz, and its a step in the right direction for me, but it's not free (I'm using their 40-day online trial right now. I'm probably going to end up writing one, in Python using Django since I have some experience with it. I know that I shouldn't be re-inventing the wheel, but in this case the wheels available just don't fit right...

Answer (score 2):

Dot Project, best so far in my view.

http://www.dotproject.net/

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out web2project yet? We forked from dotProject 2 years ago and have made some major strides. :)

Answer (score 2):

http://bugseverywhere.org/be/show/HomePage : Bugs Everywhere is a “distributed bugtracker”, designed to complement distributed revision control systems.
Supports Arch, Bazaar, Darcs, GIT, Mercurial

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in a DVCS called [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/) which has a built-in bug tracker and wiki. I've never used it but it looks like it might meet your needs.

Comment: Can you convert Mercurial repos to Fossil ones?

Comment: Probably. I had a quick look and the only thing I found was this, which isn't very helpful: http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/wiki?name=Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Mercurial extension that tries to provide this - [ArtemisExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ArtemisExtension).

Answer (score 0):

[ticgit](http://wiki.github.com/schacon/ticgit), a git based distributed ticketing system, including a command line client and web viewer. it works alongside git. but if you really need distributed source and bugtracking 
and you like this application, the cost of switching vc may be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBeamer MR looks interesting:  http://www.intland.com/products/cb-mr/overview.html
and promises to be free 'forever'...